# Converti uma matriz bidimensional para objeto no PHP. Como acessar os valores?

Tags: php, array

Olá, tenho a seguinte matriz:

```
$array[0]["nome"] = "nome exemplo";
$array[0]["idade"] = "idade exemplo";
$array[1]["nome"] = "nome exemplo 2";
$array[0]["idade"] = "idade exemplo 2";
```

Criei um objeto dessa matriz:

```
$obj = (object) $array;
```

Gostaria de saber como acessar estes valores com esse objeto, quando a matriz só tem uma dimensão eu simplesmente faço $obj->nome, mas e quando tem duas dimensões?

Comment: Converter um array que não é associativo em um objeto, não é uma boa ideia. Se fosse um array associativo, era só chamar as propriedades, na sequencia. Aqui tem uma respota onde são apresentados varios exemplos, e sugestões de como proceder nesse caso. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers

Comment: Você até pode definir propriedades númericas em um objeto mas não pode acessa-las esse é o problema, vc precisa mudar a forma de abordar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @rray disse em seu comentário

> Você até pode definir propriedades numéricas em um objeto mas não pode acessa-las esse é o problema.

Usando a funcionalidade do [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) isso fica bem claro:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($obj));
array(0) {
}
```

Ou seja ele não gerou nenhum atributo no class, mas fazendo apenas :

```
var_dump($obj);
object(stdClass)#48 (2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(12) "nome exemplo"
    ["idade"]=>
    string(13) "idade exemplo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(14) "nome exemplo 2"
    ["idade"]=>
    string(15) "idade exemplo 2"
  }
}
```

#### Possível solução

```
$array[0]["nome"] = "nome exemplo";
$array[0]["idade"] = "idade exemplo";
$array[1]["nome"] = "nome exemplo 2";
$array[1]["idade"] = "idade exemplo 2";

foreach ($array as $k => $attributes){
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        $array[$attribute][$k] = $value;
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}

$obj = (object) $array;
```

Assim você estará invertendo a ordem e gerando um array associativo. Que na conversão gera atributos na class.

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($obj));
array(2) {
  ["nome"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "nome exemplo"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "nome exemplo 2"
  }
  ["idade"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "idade exemplo"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "idade exemplo 2"
  }
}
```

Contudo como você pode notar não faz muito sentido logico fazer esta conversão já que por você ter vários valores de nome continuara tendo um array.

Answer (score 0):

Não há um bom motivo para fazer essa conversão que pretende, mas para poder capturar os elementos de `cast` do array, é necessário convertê-lo para um elemento acessível, uma das formas de fazer isso, é usando o `json_encode()` e `json_decode()`, há também outras formas de fazer esse processo, como por exemplo: `$data = get_object_vars($obj);` e `extract($data);`, a priori, para o que você precisa, o exemplo de baixo já funciona:

```
$array = array();
$array[0]["nome"] = "nome exemplo";
$array[0]["idade"] = "idade exemplo";
$array[1]["nome"] = "nome exemplo 2";
$array[0]["idade"] = "idade exemplo 2";

$obj = (object) $array;
$extractObj = json_decode(json_encode($obj));

echo $extractObj->{0}->nome;
```

Para ver a estrutura do seu objeto, use a função `var_dump($obj)`.

[**Veja esta demonstração no Ideone**](https://ideone.com/UdhImt)